# Amazon Cognito: Once a user is verified do they have to be prompted to sign in?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working with AWS Cognito. I have my sign-up flow working just fine. They user fills out their email addresss and password and I create the account in the proper `User Pool`. I have email verification enabled, and the email is sent and is received in short order. After the Sign Up screen the user is presented with a verify screen to accept the code that was just emailed. Again, this all works great.

What I am trying to understand is:

Once I have a user signed up and verified, in order for the iOS AWS SDK to do it's thing, so I need to then tell the user to go sign in or am I just missing some call that can grab their credentials once they are verified?

My guess is, since we don't know when the user verified themselves, it could be hours later and they could have killed the app and restarted it in that time that the expected flow is to have them sign in again.

Since the app does have the password in memory (NOT stored anywhere on disk) that they used to sign up in the current signup navigation controller/flow I supposed I could just force the sign-in after the verify completes.

I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something in the SDK or it's docs about this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, there is no verification flow that will skip sign-in.  One option would be to keep the password they used to sign-up in memory and if they verify immediately use that.  If they come back some time later or restart the app force them to sign in.

Comment: I think one of the things I need to work with some more is understanding when the current user is persisted. For example, if a user registers is a call to `userPool.getUser()` always that user? When I think: oh they can leave and come back from the app (aka indeterminate time to verify), how do I know it was the same user. But since it's a phone (iPhone) I think it' safe to assume it is. You wouldn't happen to know how to determine if the user returned from `getUser` has been verified would you?